# Log are shown as error when they are just info

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, fluentd, google-cloud-logging, heapster

When I'm looking at my container engine logs, I see a lot of warnings. After digging a bit further, I realized those errors are actually just logs from heapster.

I believe this is due to the log starting by `I0730`

My kubernetes cluster is using version: 1.3.2

[my latest logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94xKr.jpg)

Comment: Thanks @mastilver. This looks like a bug. I've reported it in the Google internal system. I'll let you know if our team makes progress.

Answer (score 1):

That's because Heapster is logging to stderr rather than stdout. Starting in Kubernetes 1.3, logs written to stdout got tagged with the INFO severity and logs written to stderr got tagged with the ERROR severity.

That clearly isn't working well for Heapster since it's sending all of its logs to stderr. I've opened up https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/29862 to track improving this.

Comment: Cool, so it's not an issue with Kubernetes itself but with Heapster

Comment: Yeah, it's an issue with the interface between the two changing a bit. The main takeaway is that you don't need to be concerned about the health of heapster based on its logs being displayed as error logs :)